# JSZip duplicating files and erroring on new zip creation

Tags: javascript, zip, jszip

My existing code allows users to upload a zipped file and passes that file onto another function for more processing. In between those steps, I'd like to add logic that checks the contents of the zipped files, makes any necessary modifications, and passes the new zip file along. I've written the following:

```
JSZip.loadAsync(file).then(function(zip) {
    zip.forEach(function(relativePath, zipEntry) {
        //Change extension name
        fName = zipEntry.name.substr(0, zipEntry.name.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".docx";
        zip.file(fName, zipEntry, { compression: "DEFLATE" });
        console.log(zip.file(fName, zipEntry, { compression: "DEFLATE" }));
        zip.generateAsync({type: "blob"}).then(function(content) {
            saveAs(content, "test.zip");
        });
    });
});
```

I am admittedly new to JavaScript, but I believe I've narrowed down the issues.

First issue is file duplication, as the console.log output tells me that 4 files are found within the JSZip object, yet the original upload only contained 2 files, "example_file.doc" and "example_file2.doc":

```
example_file.doc: ZipObject {name: "example_file.docx", dir: false, date: Wed Feb 20 2019 08:42:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Daylight Time), comment: null, unixPermissions: null, …}
example_file.docx: ZipObject {name: "example_file.docx", dir: false, date: Tue Feb 26 2019 11:39:23 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), comment: null, unixPermissions: null, …}
example_file2.doc: ZipObject {name: "example_file2.docx", dir: false, date: Wed Feb 20 2019 09:07:04 GMT-0500 (Eastern Daylight Time), comment: null, unixPermissions: null, …}
example_file2.docx: ZipObject {name: "example_file2.docx", dir: false, date: Tue Feb 26 2019 11:39:23 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), comment: null, unixPermissions: null, …}
```

The next issue is an error that is likely directly related to the above issue:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Can't read the data of 'example_file.docx'. Is it in a supported JavaScript type (String, Blob, ArrayBuffer, etc)

This error outputs to the console 4 times in total and references the 4 files. I'm sure it's due to an issue with my zip.generateAsync code, but having never worked with Blobs or Promises, I'm not sure what the root cause of the issue is.

Lastly, I'm unsure of how to keep the newly generated zip file (if I could generate one properly) in memory and send it to the next function. Right now there's code in place to save it locally, but that's not the end goal and is more of a placeholder.

Any help with these issues would be much appreciated, even if it's just a hint or a step in the right direction.